# Creating a dictionary another sorted dictionary out of this code on Python thanks

Tags: python, windows, dictionary

So I already have everything done, however. I cannot figure out how to make a sorted dictionary out of the dictionary I have created. This dictionary should have the team that won the most games as 1st and so on.

This was the first dictionary I created 
[img of dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKLc0.png)

I have attempted
`sorted_wins = sorted(matches_won[team].items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)`

but I keep getting met with an: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

```
fp = open("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/WorldSeries.txt", "r")

matches = {}

matches_won = {}

year = 1903

for team in fp.readlines():

    team = team.strip()

    matches[year] = team

    if team not in matches_won:

        matches_won[team] = 0

    matches_won[team]+=1

    year += 1

fp.close()
sorted_wins = sorted(matches_won[team].items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
for team in matches_won:

    print(team,":",matches_won[team])

again = "Y"

while again=="Y":

    year = int(input("\n Enter a year in the range of 1903 through 2019: "))

    if(year>=1903 and year<=2017):

        print(matches[year], "team won match in",year)
        print(matches_won[team])

else:

    print("Invalid year")

again = input("\nWant to continue playing?(Y - yes, N - no): ").upper()
```

Trying to approaches that I've gotten I still only have this dictionary

[Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVdUU.png)

This is the dictionary:

```
matches_won = {'Boston Americans' : 1,
'World Series Not Played in 1904' : 1,
'New York Giants' : 5,
'Chicago White Sox' : 3,
'Chicago Cubs' : 3,
'Pittsburgh Pirates' : 5,
'Philadelphia Athletics' : 5,
'Boston Red Sox' : 8,
'Boston Braves' : 1,
'Cincinnati Reds' : 5,
'Cleveland Indians' : 2,
'New York Yankees' : 27,
'Washington Senators' : 1,
'St. Louis Cardinals' : 11,
'Detroit Tigers' : 4,
'Brooklyn Dodgers' : 1,
'Milwaukee Braves' : 1,
'Los Angeles Dodgers' : 5,
'Baltimore Orioles' : 3,
'New York Mets' : 2,
'Oakland Athletics' : 4,
'Philadelphia Phillies' : 2,
'Kansas City Royals' : 2,
'Minnesota Twins' : 2,
'Toronto Blue Jays' : 2,
'World Series Not Played in 1994' : 1,
'Atlanta Braves' : 1,
'Florida Marlins' : 2,
'Arizona Diamondbacks' : 1,
'Anaheim Angels' : 1,
'San Francisco Giants' : 3,
'Houston Astros' : 1,
'Washington Nationals' : 1}
```

Comment: Give an example for the dictionaries

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Just included a link to the dictionary that I created

Comment: you meant, you want it sorted by that values?

Comment: Yes, so I wanted that dictionary to be sorted by the team that won the most World Series to the team that won the least.  @JoshuaVarghese

Comment: ok does the answer work?

Comment: How can you make a sorted dictionary, Dictionaries are intrinsically unsorted. Displaying the dictionary is another matter.

Comment: @NSR dictionaries can be sorted :)

Comment: It's not giving me the "Attribute error" anymore, but it did not give me the sorted dictionary.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/s2kzn3 This is what I'm getting. Unless I placed the code in the wrong place.

Comment: could you copy that dictionary and paste it here?

Comment: are the values integers?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese You might be right but I am trying to find evidence of that online but just can't. I understand you can remember the sequence of the order but you can't order the list. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key . Am I missing something?

Comment: I see there's another approach. I'll try that. As for copying and pasting the dictionary. You want me to paste it in my original post...? And yes they are integers.

Comment: ya, posting the dictionary helps us be sure of the output :)

Comment: @KDAssignments if my matches_won is same as the matches_won you have, then this works :)

Comment: Just posted it (last image link labeled as "Dictionary"). I think it may not be working because of where I put it in my code. Want to see? @JoshuaVarghese

Comment: is your matches_won same as the Matches_won i've given in my answer?

Comment: @KDAssignments the dictionary is an image :) i cant copy that to work :)

Comment: ahhh sorry, my code is missing the portion when I inputed a plain text file from my computer which was the list used to create a dictionary. I sincerely apologize. I need to edit it.  Also yes my matches won is the same. @JoshuaVarghese

Comment: @KDAssignments is my correction correct it into a dictionary you have?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Yes, sorry that is correct.

Comment: Works! Thanks :D @JoshuaVarghese

Comment: sure, welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume :

```
 matches_won = {'Boston Americans' : 1,
'World Series Not Played in 1904' : 1,
'New York Giants' : 5,
'Chicago White Sox' : 3,
'Chicago Cubs' : 3,
'Pittsburgh Pirates' : 5,
'Philadelphia Athletics' : 5,
'Boston Red Sox' : 8,
'Boston Braves' : 1,
'Cincinnati Reds' : 5,
'Cleveland Indians' : 2,
'New York Yankees' : 27,
'Washington Senators' : 1,
'St. Louis Cardinals' : 11,
'Detroit Tigers' : 4,
'Brooklyn Dodgers' : 1,
'Milwaukee Braves' : 1,
'Los Angeles Dodgers' : 5,
'Baltimore Orioles' : 3,
'New York Mets' : 2,
'Oakland Athletics' : 4,
'Philadelphia Phillies' : 2,
'Kansas City Royals' : 2,
'Minnesota Twins' : 2,
'Toronto Blue Jays' : 2,
'World Series Not Played in 1994' : 1,
'Atlanta Braves' : 1,
'Florida Marlins' : 2,
'Arizona Diamondbacks' : 1,
'Anaheim Angels' : 1,
'San Francisco Giants' : 3,
'Houston Astros' : 1,
'Washington Nationals' : 1}
```

is the dictionary to be sorted is descending order by value.
Then:

```
sorted_wins = {i:matches_won[i] for i in sorted(matches_won,key = lambda x:matches_won[x],reverse = True)}
```

or, another approach is:

```
dict(sorted(matches_won.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse = True))
```

this gives:

```
{'New York Yankees': 27,
'St. Louis Cardinals': 11, 
'Boston Red Sox': 8, 
'New York Giants': 5, 
'Pittsburgh Pirates': 5, 
'Philadelphia Athletics': 5, 
'Cincinnati Reds': 5, 
'Los Angeles Dodgers': 5, 
'Detroit Tigers': 4, 
'Oakland Athletics': 4, 
'Chicago White Sox': 3, 
'Chicago Cubs': 3, 
'Baltimore Orioles': 3, 
'San Francisco Giants': 3, 
'Cleveland Indians': 2, 
'New York Mets': 2, 
'Philadelphia Phillies': 2, 
'Kansas City Royals': 2, 
'Minnesota Twins': 2, 
'Toronto Blue Jays': 2, 
'Florida Marlins': 2, 
'Boston Americans': 1, 
'World Series Not Played in 1904': 1, 
'Boston Braves': 1, 
'Washington Senators': 1, 
'Brooklyn Dodgers': 1, 
'Milwaukee Braves': 1, 
'World Series Not Played in 1994': 1, 
'Atlanta Braves': 1, 
'Arizona Diamondbacks': 1, 
'Anaheim Angels': 1, 
'Houston Astros': 1, 
'Washington Nationals': 1}
```

Comment: The last approach could just be `dict(sorted(matches_won.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))`

Comment: @RoadRunner A list can be made to dict?